# Set custom id session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I have maybe trivial question but how can i set custom id session in rails?
I need this because Apple’s Safari web browser is configured to block third-party cookies by default and i needd some workaround to pass session variables in my facebook application.
I would like to set this id in GET variable.

I have :active_record_store for session_store.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly access the session variable and store anything inside it. Session variable is a hash. So maybe you want to access it as `session[:id] = "value"`. I don't know if you are looking for this or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Changing or setting the session_id manually is not a good idea. I would recommend authenticating the user with the facebook cookie and then you should send all requiered parameters with each request.

[Facebook Cookies](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/cookies/)

Comment: yes i know that changing manually is not good. But there is only way in Safari to use access token on another page inside iframe. Because when i redirect to another page in iframe Safari is setting up new cookie session and i dont have access to the prevois cookie. Generally safari is creating new cookie for each redirect.